# CORS issue even if i have used @CrossOrigin at the REST API

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, rest, cors, cross-origin-resource-policy

For one of our rest API created we need to allow cross origin,
SO i have annotated it at our method level with @CrossOrigin

```
 @CrossOrigin
@PostMapping(value = "/assignbadge", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<Object> assignBadge(@Parameter(description = "Badge Assignment Input", required = true) @RequestBody final AssitTag assitTag, @Context final HttpServletRequest request) throws IBusConnectionException
{
```

Then i am trying  this API from html and JavaSript.

Like below

```
fetch("https://capgt-api.eng.us.devcare*w*re.net/tagament/v1/assignbadge", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Tenant-Short-Name": "DWXENG",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization,Tenant-Short-Name,Accept",
      "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhb....."
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(json),
  })
```

But however i try with other filters also i always get preflight fail like below
[image]

[image]

I tried resolving CORS errors by adding other global filters but whatever i use i get this error. API is working in swagger and postman with the headers. Only CORS filters headers are used extra here for CORS error.I need solution to hit my API through JS

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide origin like so (replace the url with your client's url):

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
....
```

Comment: @pssuj you should probably use `http://127.0.0.1:5500` (or https if you have SSL)

Comment: No this is not working.Same error

Comment: I don't understand your question, you show code that sends POST request but then in the screenshot there is an OPTIONS request, you say that you send the request to a localhost URL but the code example you send it to some other URL. can you clarify your question

Comment: and if you are using CrossOrigin you don't need to add all these headers and you don't need to set the mode to 'cors'.

Comment: I am using POST request itself for the URL mentioned as un code not localhost.But post triggers a preflight request with options method which blocks the actual post request.SO that screenshot is been mentioned